# Need most recent file name (and modification date) for each folder in a server tree

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

Moving server with 13TB of data to new site. Data pipe constraints (1TB/day) prevents it all being moved in the time available (over a weekend). We want to move just the 'active' folders first, the the rest later.  Need a command line that will recursively find which folders have files that have been modified in the last x days.

Comment: [`man 1 find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for starters.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question itself :)

```
 find /dir -type d -ctime +x
```

or

```
 find /dir -type f -mtime +x -printf '%h'
```

Where */dir* the directory where find should start. You can use '-atime', if last access is required. However atime depends on filesystem mount options.

See: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html